# Set TextBlock's ToolTip content

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, textblock

I am trying to add a `ToolTip` on my `TextBlock`. After some research this is how I added it on `UWP`

xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="flyList" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#FF7C7C7C">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped">
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip Name="tip1" Content="Click to copy signal to clipboard."/>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

How can I set the `ToolTip`'s content? Or better how can I even access it?
I want to access it on `TextBlock`'s tapped event.

```
private void TextBlock_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    /*
    var send = sender as TextBlock;
    var dataPackage = new DataPackage { RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy };
    dataPackage.SetText(send.Text);
    Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
    */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void TextBlock_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var txt = sender as TextBlock;
    ToolTip tt = ToolTipService.GetToolTip(txt) as ToolTip;
    tt.Content = "...";
}
```

And please tag your questions properly. UWP is not the same thing as WPF.

Comment: Sorry, my fault for the tag. I think I will need to reset its content once selection changed or even better use a selectionchanged event instead of tapped. Thank you